# Logic gates - Creating a Digital counter

Tags: digital-logic

I'm wanting to create the following digital counter using only basic logic gates (AND, OR, NOT, NAND, NOR, etc):

[image]

I've done some searching and the answers provided are much more complex than what I'm actually after.

I'm just wondering if it would look something like this? 
[image]

Comment: Do you know how to create a D flip flop from gates?

Comment: Wow!  a master-slave flip-flop! I haven't seen one of those since the 70's. That won't work in place of a D-flop, because the output doesn't change until the clock falls in a M/S flop.

Comment: It's almost as if you copied it right from another page...   Is there a real question here?  .....  http://webpages.charter.net/dawill/tmoranwms/Elec_Flipflop.html

Comment: Yes I did just grab the image from images. Also @uint128_t I do know how to create a D flip flop (or D-latch?). I'm just wondering how you link multiple ones together? Do you just need to link the output of the first one to be the input of the second one and so forth?

Comment: If you're trying to create a counter, then yes, you take your DFFs and arrange them as the upper diagram shows. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: The counter circuit you've shown is OK except for no set and reset inputs.  [**Go here**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5474.pdf) for the logic diagram and transistor-level schematic of a dflop.

Comment: The point I was trying to say is **how** that upper diagram can be created using basic logic gates. I don't really understand those designs and all I'm trying to do first up is learn how to use basic logic gates to create certain things. In this case a counter. I've quickly and messily drawn this one up that uses three blocks of D flip flops and I'm wondering if it's a step in the right direction of implementation. http://i.imgur.com/9celA3v.png  I'm no electrical engineer student, just a Computer science student wanting to extend upon the little material given to us about this sort of stuff.

Comment: Do not confuse a D-flop with a D-latch. A D-flop is edge-triggered and a D-latch turns transparent when the gate is high (the latch's gate is very different from the flop's clock). The latch certainly won't work for your counter. Because of the edge-triggered nature of the D-flop, I don't think you can build one from gates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second schematic is almost a direct replacement of the DFF in the first schematic. The convention for the clock of FF is positive edge triggered (output change on positive edge). But the bottom schematic's FF is negative edge triggered and the clock label should be \$ \overline{CLK} \$ or equivalent.

Therefore, if you take four copies of the bottom schematic, insert them in place of the DFF above while inverting each of the clock, then you have the equivalent of the top schematic (which is a 4-bit ripple up counter) in discrete gates.

By the way, the explanations of flip-flops found on the Web are full of errors.

---

Response to comment:

In your comment, you have included a schematic that have the equivalent of two flip flops. To make that into a two bit ripple counter, you need to make some corrections, as in here:

[image: ![enter image description here]

By feeding-back \$ \overline{Q} \$ to D, the connection causes the FF to toggle at the active clock edge. By connecting the output of the first FF to the clock of the second, the two toggle FFs become a 2-bit ripple counter.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the behavior of the master/slave flip-flop. It is not edge-triggered at all. The D input is sampled when the clock (which is better described as a gate) goes high. When the gate goes low, the state of the master latch (which has been tracking the D input) is transferred to the slave latch, and on to the output. Master/Slave flip-flops were used before edge-triggered D and J-K flops were created, but became obsolete in the 70's. They won't work in that ripple counter, because the flops output won't change when the gate goes high.

Comment: I tried doing something like this http://i.imgur.com/4VHjtDi.png Not sure how they are to be linked together properly (there are two DFF's here). Also @Mark, there's gotta be a way to do it with basic gates isn't there? I remember seeing a specific question saying to create a  counter with logic gates.

Comment: @mark When clock is high, the first latch is "enabled", presenting the input to the second latch, while the second latch is in latched mode, ignoring the inputs while holding on to the previous value. When the clock goes low, the first latch latches the data and ignore the input, the second latch present that data to the output. The transfer of data from input to output occurs at the falling edge. It is a negative edge trigger flip flop.

Comment: @rioraxe - OK, I can see what you mean now. Because the output changes on the negative edge, it can be interpreted an edge triggered flop, but with a long setup time and a near zero hold time (which is good for this). So it may work for a counter, if counting on the negative edge was acceptable. If not, then an extra inverter on the clock is all you need.

Comment: @mark - nothing especially long about the setup time. If it looks like a duck, walks a duck, quacks like a duck ...

Comment: I would consider three gate delays a long setup time, when most flops have a setup time less than one gate delay (and some JKs have a zero or negative setup time).